# ipython -pylab debugging: Can I stop the execution at a specific line and drop into the shell?

Tags: python, numpy, debugging, matplotlib

When writing python code (mostly *numpy + matplotlib*), I usually just type the code in *vim* and run the program to test it:

`python2 foo.py`

Occasionally, when this is not sufficient and I need to inspect the problem more thoroughly, I just launch the program in ipython:
`ipython -pylab foo.py`, and then inspect the variables, test some commands and so on. I like `ipython`, because of the tab completion and the availability of *bash* commands.

This worked well enough for me, but now my programs grew bigger and include many subroutines (in multiple files). The `ipython` approach doesn't work any more, because it always runs the **complete code** till the end of `foo.py` (when it drops into the pylab shell). What I'd like to do instead is, stop execution at a given line in a subroutine (could be in another file) and inspect variables there. **I.e. set a break point at which the pylab shell kicks in.**

Is there an *easy way* to adapt my `ipython` way of working? E.g. stop at a line in `bar.py`

```
ipython -pylab --stop-at bar.py:423 foo.py
```

or, stop at a subroutine name in `bar.py`

```
ipython -pylab --stop-at bar.py:subroutine-name foo.py
```

Comment: by the way, `ipython`'s `-pdb` option, only calls the python debugger if an exception is caught. That's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 5):

You can import the pdb module into the code and then add a pdb.set_trace() call where you would like to have the code stop. Ipython will drop into the interactive debugger, and you are free to step though your code as you wish.

Comment: thanks for your answer @talonmies. What you suggest actually starts the debugger not the ipython/pylab shell. But, if I hit Ctrl+D, I'm actually in the ipython/pylab shell at the correct place! But, I'm not very happy: 1. extra lines in `bar.py` are really not justifiable for quick testing and 2. Also `python2 foo.py` will start the debugger...

Comment: You can easily make debugging breakpoints conditional and only have the conditions set when running interactively or when a specific module is specific to the interpreter from the command line. If you don't understand how that can be done, I can edit examples into the answer.

Comment: When I exit the debugger using Ctrl+D, I'm dropped to the ipython/pylab shell. This would be acceptable, but it does not work in a sub-routine. :-(

Answer (score 5):

You can drop into a IPython debug session by inserting the following code at the desired point:

```
import sys, IPython
IPython.Shell.IPShell(argv=[])
IPython.Debugger.Pdb(IPython.ipapi.get().options.colors).set_trace(sys._getframe())
```

Not exactly what you seem to be looking for, but it works quite nicely for me. It also makes it really easy to have complex conditional breakpoints. There are several other methods of starting an IPython debug session from within your source file floating around on the web, but this - in my experience anyway - is the most reliable in terms of loading the correct colours, tab completion working properly etc.

Once the debug session has started you can set further breakpoints using the `break` command:

```
ipdb> break test.py:11
Breakpoint 1 at /tmp/test.py:11
ipdb> b my_function
Breakpoint 2 at /tmp/test.py:5
```

To make it easy to insert, you can set a macro/key combination in your editor. I'm also a Vim user and I have the following keymap in my `vimrc`:

```
nmap <C-P><C-D> oimport sys, IPython<CR>IPython.Shell.IPShell(argv=[])<CR>IPython.Debugger.Pdb(IPython.ipapi.get().options.colors).set_trace(sys._getframe())<ESC>:w<CR>
```

From normal mode, pressing Ctrl-P then Ctrl-D inserts the debug code **after** the current line with the correct indentation and then saves the file.

Comment: thanks for the answer, @Blair. I tested your suggestion and can confirm that it works. Basically I'm seeing the same behaviour as in @talonmies answer, but with colours and auto-complete. After hitting Ctrl-D I'm in the place I want (the ipython/pylab shell). Your vim short-cut is helpful, though. +1

Comment: For reference: recent version of Ipython do not have the Ipython.Shell attribute. To drop into a shell you should use `from IPython import embed

embed()`